# OOP Design - Passing class member variables as method arguments within class

Tags: c++, oop

Here are simple examples code, its not the best:

Using members without passing it in arguments:

```
class Car
{
public:
  void doSomething()
  {
    // doing something
    onEngineFailure();
  }
private:
  void onEngineFailure()
  {
    // Operate on m_Engine
  }
private:
  Engine m_Engine;
};
```

Passing members as arguments:

```
class Car
{
public:
    void doSomething()
    {
        // doing something
        onEngineFailure(m_Engine);
    }
private:
  void onEngineFailure(const Engine& engine)
  {
    // Operate on engine
  }
private:
  Engine m_Engine;
};
```

In first example, method `onEngineFailure` operates directly on class member variable `m_Engine`. There is no point to pass it as function argument, as car can have only one engine and engine that `onEngineFailure` operates on will be always `m_Engine`.

In second example, method `onEngineFailure` operates on engine passed by argument. Which will always be `m_Engine` anyway.

So, which one is in design more correct? If method has already access to member variable and it will always operate only on it, then why passing it as argument.
However, the same could be said about global variables, but global variables should be used as least as possible.

Comment: I'd say the 1st one is better.

Answer (score 3):

> So, which one is in design more correct? If method has already access
>   to member variable and it will always operate only on it, then why
>   passing it as argument.

Exactly.<sup>1</sup>

> However, the same could be said about global variables,

Except variables tied to a particular object instance are kept separate from other instances, and their coherency is managed at object level. Thanks to the encapsulation, you're able to hide them away and ensure they're used correctly.

By analogy, all variables reside in RAM, but are they are global just because of that? No, because it's the logical distinction between them that counts.

---

<sup>1</sup>In this example, it probably doesn't make much sense. However, if the functionality of the function was generic enough to be also used by *other* classes, it could make sense to make it a free function or a static public function. The ability to make a function static is sometimes important also for other reasons, and in those cases explicit (sometimes directly `this`) arguments make it possible/easier.

Comment: I was going to complement your answer with your footnote. I do agree.

Comment: Agreed, IMHO, for future steps of this class, http://www.ndepend.com/docs/code-metrics#LCOM should be considered also. methods of class should use, defined attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The first code snippet is elegant and clean way. Since member function have access to data members you dont need data members to be passed as argument.

if you want to change state of data member(m_Engine) based on external input you would expect an argument of (Engine ) type. and it will be done in following manner.

```
void doSomething(Engine engine)
{
    // doing something
    onEngineFailure(engine);
}
void onEngineFailure(const Engine& engine)
{
  // copy it here say m_Engine.model=engine.model;
}
```